# Term-rewriting software recommendation

Tags: term-rewriting

Is there an easy to use software that implements term-rewriting? Or do I need to write my own parser for it?

I am looking for something that will take in a fixed set of user-specified rules and will be able to reduce arbitrary terms under those rules. Is there a standard tool for doing such rewrites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PLT Redex](https://redex.racket-lang.org/) has support for term rewriting. You'll find that most of the examples are focused on small-step operational semantics for programming languages, but in general the system allows for arbitrary rewriting, including non-determinism. It also has a bunch of nice features, like randomized testing of properties, alpha-equivalence, steppers for visualising/debugging, and excellent graphical output.

If you want higher-order syntax, you might be interested in something like [ELPI](https://github.com/LPCIC/elpi).

For a super-lightweight prolog-style programming, you might be interested in [miniKanren](http://minikanren.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The computer language Prolog has a term parser built in, and you can represent re-write rules in Prolog clauses, see

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2Px7cu2a68